# How to find size of files in D: drive using python

Tags: python

I have installed python 3.6 in C: drive, on windows 10. I want to find size of file in D: drive.

Comment: You will have to pass the path as `"D:\\"`

Comment: for every folder its giving result as 4096. its not matching with file sizes.        Example what I tried is  :                                                                     >>> b = ntpath.getsize('E:\\Practice')
>>> b
4096

Comment: I do not see the suggestion of using `ntpath.getsize` in the linked question. Have you tried passing the path to the function in the accepted answer to this post?